# Android Check for similar data in row

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to check if a field in my database already exists and to do so i'm using this method in my DBAdapter to do that. I'm not sure this is the best solution.

```
public Cursor getRowByName(String rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ACT + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then, when i click in my button i do:

```
Cursor data = myDb.getRowByName(item);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It dosent exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
```

My 'item' his the string i want to check. 
Can't find out what i'm doing wrong, but i'm a little new to android so if you guys can give me a hint i would aprecciate a lot :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to use where and whereArgs:

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_ACT + "= ?", new String[]{rowId},
    null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cursor.getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) to check number of result in cursor result from query as:

```
Cursor data = myDb.getRowByName(item);
 if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
   // record found in db
  }
  else { 
   // record not found in db                
   }
```

Comment: Still dosent work, i get the same error : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "House": syntax error (code 1): , while compliling (...)

I think the query is working since it shows in the error, but i dont know what is causing this error, thought it had to be my cursor but dosent look like...


EDIT: "House" is the string that i want to find in this case

Comment: I think it would help if you showed where "House" is

Comment: @DanielFerreira : do it as `String where = KEY_ACT + "='" + rowId+"'";`

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly made it, i did it like you guys suggested and it's working.

My DBAdapter method:

public Cursor getRowByName(String name) {

```
String where = KEY_ACT + "=" + name;
Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_ACT + "= ?", new String[{name},
        null, null, null, null);
if (c != null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
}
return c;
```

}

And im my class:

```
Cursor data = myDb.getRowByName(item);
                if(data.moveToFirst()) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It dosent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    long newId = myDb.insertRow( timerValue.getText().toString(), item);
                    Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(newId);
                    displayRecordSet(cursor);
                }
```

Thanks you @tachyonflux , i think that was part of my problem :) And thank you @ρяσѕρєя K for the help !